# Get specific records from DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables, and values:

```js
t_cars
---------------------------------------------------------
nCars_ID sName  sModel  sIdentifier 
---------------------------------------------------------
1  BMW  3 series D-78-JHG
2  Volvo  C30  B-56-KHT
3  Fiat  Doblo  H-72-ABN
4  Volvo  C40  J-78-YTR


t_feature
---------------------------
nFeature_ID  sName
---------------------------
1   CMC
2   Doors
3   Color
4   Type
5   Weight
6   Engine
7   Power


t_cars_feature
-------------------------------------------------------------------
nCarsFeature_ID nCars_ID nFeature_ID  sValue
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  2  1   2500
2  2  2   5
3  2  4   Diesel
4  2  3   Green
5  3  1   1900
6  3  2   3
7  3  4   Otto
8  3  5   2300 KG
9  1  1   1900
10  1  3   Blue
11  1  4   Diesel
12  1  5   2100 KG
```

I need to retrieve from DB the cars that has CMC feature, has Color feature, AND CMC = 1900 AND Color = 'Blue' ONLY

I have tried:

```
SELECT t_cars.sName, t_cars.sModel, t_cars.sIdentifier 
FROM t_cars, t_feature, t_cars_feature 
WHERE t_feature.nFeature_ID = t_cars_feature.nFeature_ID 
AND t_cars.nCars_ID = t_cars_feature.nCars_ID
AND [/*condition that get me cars that has CMC feature, has Color feature, AND CMC = 1900 AND Color = 'Blue' ONLY*/]
```

I have tried the condition like that:
**Trial 1:**

```
AND t_feature.sName = 'CMC'
AND t_feature.sName = 'Color'
AND t_cars_feature.sValue = '1900'
AND t_cars_feature.sValue = 'Blue'
```

and get me nothing

I have also tried:
**Trial 2:**

```
AND t_feature.sName IN ('CMC','Color')
AND t_cars_feature.sValue IN ('1900','Blue')
```

and get me all records that has CMC 1900 OR color 'Blue' (probably I got here an cartesian product)

In real situation I could have several t_feature.sName values, and several t_cars_feature.sValue values, *that is why trial 1 are not suitable for me* ...

Can you help me ? Thank you.

Comment: which database you are using sql-server or mysql ?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 ... does it matter ?

Comment: yes, it does matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t_cars        
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t_cars_feature AS cf 
                       JOIN t_feature AS f ON (f.nFeature_ID = cf.nFeature_ID)
              WHERE t_cars.nCars_ID = cf.nCars_ID AND f.sName = 'CMC' AND cf.sValue = '1900')     
      AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t_cars_feature AS cf 
                       JOIN t_feature AS f ON (f.nFeature_ID = cf.nFeature_ID)
              WHERE t_cars.nCars_ID = cf.nCars_ID AND f.sName = 'Color' AND cf.sValue = 'Blue');
```

[See the full example here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29be9/18)

I would like to comment about some of the things you've done there:

- It is generally considered a bad practice to notate the type as a prefix in the column name, or in the object's name.
- Your usage of the IN clause is wrong. I suggest you to try and practice about this matter a bit. When you supply a list of values inside the IN clause, it means that any of those values should result in a true value for the predicate - not that both of the them should exists.
- Please note that when you use the WHERE clause with multiple predicates separated by an "AND", you require all of them to exists in a SINGLE row. Check out the result of your JOIN and see if this is the case to understand the case better.
- It is considered a better practice to use a JOIN (i.e. INNER JOIN) and not a cartesian product (,) - even though both queries will usually compile into the same execution plan. It is just more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with EXISTS and NOT EXISTS:

```
--Alias = Table
--    C = t_cars
--   CF = t_cars_feature
--    F = t_feature

SELECT * 
  FROM t_cars C
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM t_cars_feature CF INNER JOIN t_feature F ON CF.nFeature_ID = F.nFeature_ID
                WHERE CF.nCars_ID = C.nCars_ID --matches t_cars ID 
                  AND F.sName = 'CMC' --has CMC feature
                  AND F.sName = 'Color' --has color feature
                  AND CF.sValue = '1900'  --CMC = 1900 
                  AND CF.sValue = 'Blue'  --Color = 'Blue'
              )
   AND NOT EXISTS 
              (SELECT *
                 FROM t_cars_feature CF INNER JOIN t_feature F ON CF.nFeature_ID = F.nFeature_ID
                WHERE CF.nCars_ID = C.nCars_ID --matches t_cars ID 
                  AND F.sName = 'CMC' --has CMC feature
                  AND F.sName = 'Color' --has color feature
                  AND CF.sValue = '1900'  --CMC = 1900 
                  AND CF.sValue <> 'Blue'  --Color = 'Blue ONLY'
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make some use of conditional aggregation to get the desired results

```
SELECT t_cars.sName, t_cars.sModel, t_cars.sIdentifier 
FROM t_cars
JOIN t_cars_feature  ON t_cars.nCars_ID = t_cars_feature.nCars_ID 
JOIN t_feature ON t_feature.nFeature_ID = t_cars_feature.nFeature_ID 
WHERE t_feature.sName IN ('CMC','Color')
GROUP BY t_cars.sName, t_cars.sModel, t_cars.sIdentifier
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t_feature.sName ='CMC' AND t_cars_feature.sValue ='1900' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN t_feature.sName ='Color' AND t_cars_feature.sValue ='Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >0
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0ee8/10)

Comment: Why do such a thing when you can just query it properly?